# How to migrate state passed in React-Router to Redux Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So far, I have been using `React` with `React-Router` and when passing data between `URL`s, I have been passing the state as

```
this.props.history.push(Routes.transactionEdit, this.state.transaction);
```

This is documented [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

and in the Component, I would use it as

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userId: props.history.location.state.userId,
        transactionId: props.history.location.state.id,
        createdAt: props.history.location.state.createdAt,
        name: props.history.location.state.name,
        amount: props.history.location.state.amount,
    }
}
```

However, I learned that managing state in `Redux` is a better idea and it helps test the store separately from how the views look. and I liked that idea because I care about the clean-testable code.

I started refactoring code and for many parts where I need data from the database, I was able to migrate the code using `thunk` pattern. However, with this use case where the state is sent as part of `history.push`, I don't know how to put this state into the `Redux` Store.

**Question**
How do I migrate the state in `this.props.history.push(Routes.transactionEdit, this.state.transaction);` (during push) to the `Redux` store, so that it can be managed outside of `React` Component?

Thanks

Comment: it really doesnt work like that. if you use redux, each time you make changes, you wont change the state instead you would change the redux store. so you dont have to push it this way. but if you are hgell bent on pushing data this way, createan action & reducer to handle it and just dispatch the action before pushing

Comment: As mentioned above, you'll ultimately move your entire state to the Redux store, which means that every component could access it if you `connect()` it (so there's no need to pass data when switching between routes). Also consider [`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux), if relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to setup a specific `action` that is specifically meant for taking a component's state and pushes it to Redux's store. Of course you'll need to have your reducer respond appropriately to that action.
If youre new to Redux, this might be opening a big can of worms.